# Android activity, will finish() kill my countdowntimer thread?

Tags: android, service, android-activity, lifecycle, countdowntimer

my activity starts a countdowntimer thread, this thread will also attempt to update the UI thread when if finishes

the activity itself may be `finish()`ed before this countdown ends. if the activity goes, will the countdowntimer go as well?

if so, I may need to run the countdowntimer in a service instead

Comment: You should try this out, it doesn't seem like a hard thing to determine.

Comment: yes @A--C this is true, but my actual use case required updating the UI thread, an adapter in a listview which read from a serialized object cached in externalstorage, so all of the scenarios would have actually been time consuming for me to analyze, especially if the real answer is simply "move it in a service"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't necessarily. 
Your thread will be around as long as the process does not get killed. The process does not get killed immediately by the operating system even if you have no foreground activities. Not having them just increase the probability of getting it killed.

Having a reference from your thread to the activity may also result in increasing your app's memory footprint, since your activity won't be garbage collected because your thread is still pointing at it. You should consider (at least) to use a weak reference in this case.

Finally, given that your intention is to have your countdown time active even if your app is in background, you should consider moving it into a service.

Comment: yes, thank you, as I was writing this I realized it would be wiser to put it in a service regardless of the outcome of the answers. But I remained curious